# Equation solving python

Tags: python, equation

I want to find x in x=[(b+x)*c/d]-a or (a+x)/(b+x)=c/d where a,b,c,d are inputs from the user.(im a beginner and i just started learning python but i dont know how to solve and equation with it)

```
`a,b,c,d=input().split()
 a=int(a)
 b=int(b)
 c=int(c)
 d=int(d)`
```

this is what i did currently. i also tried to use something called sympy but i dont understand it because it is my first time writing code and english is not my native lang.(i already installed numpy and sympy but i dont know how to use them(i only know to import them)

Comment: Have you tried searching online for an introductory guide or a tutorial? There is tons of material for you to read for both numpy and sympy.

Comment: `(a + x) / (b + x) = c / d` simplifies to `ad + dx = bc + cx`, which in turn simplifies to `x = (ad - bc) / (c - d)`. You don't need numpy or sympy to solve this equation

Comment: Assuming you are trying to learn how to code, I'd like to advise you to start with something simpler. Clearly, you know math. start doing things that you do understand and can write.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can use Sympy to solve the equations mentioned:

1. Define the variable `x` as a symbol.
2. Then, you can define your equation using the `Eq` function.
3. Use the `solve` function to solve the equation.

Like so:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

# Define x as a symbol
x = symbols('x')

# Get inputs from the user
a, b, c, d = map(int, input().split())

# Define and solve the first equation: x = [(b + x) * c / d] - a
equation1 = Eq(x, ((b + x) * c / d) - a)
solution1 = solve(equation1, x)
print("Solution for the first equation:", solution1)

# Define and solve the second equation: (a + x) / (b + x) = c / d
equation2 = Eq((a + x) / (b + x), c / d)
solution2 = solve(equation2, x)
print("Solution for the second equation:", solution2)
```

When you run the code, it will prompt you to enter the values for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. After entering the values, it will print the solutions for both equations.

Note: Equations can have multiple solutions, zero solutions, or infinite solutions. The solve function will return a list of solutions. If there's no solution, the list will be empty. If there are infinite solutions, it will return a general solution.

Comment: Comments are transient. If you'd like to add more information to your answer, you should make an [edit].